# Do Browsers Load Hidden Assets

Tags: html, css, performance, optimization

If an asset (for example, a .jpg image) is found in the DOM, but marked with 'display: none' CSS, which browsers will download that asset, even though it doesn't technically display it to the user?

This is a website load speed question. I want to know how CSS display properties affect page load time. This question **has** been asked before on StackOverflow. However, that was two years ago, and I've heard rumors that things have changed since then.

Comment: Open up your browsers developer tools, go to the network tab then load the page with the hidden asset and see if it loads.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Internet Explorer versions 6+ all appear to load the image. Firefox doesn't appear to load the image in versions 3-5, but do load the image from version 6 and up. As for Chrome, the image would be loaded at least as far back as version 14. Safari 4 and up also load the image.

Run the test yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/4L9adwcu/

```js
(function () {

    var image = document.createElement( "img" ),
        timeout = setTimeout(function timeout () {
            alert( "Image was not loaded." );
        }, 3000);

    function loaded () {
        clearInterval( timeout );
        alert( "Image was loaded." );
    }

    if ( image.addEventListener ) {
        image.addEventListener( "load", loaded );
    } else if ( image.attachEvent ) {
        image.attachEvent( "onload", loaded );
    }

    image.style.display = "none";
    image.src = "http://gravatar.com/avatar/a84a8714fd33f6676743f9734a824feb";

    document.body.appendChild( image );

}());
```

If I had to speculate as to why this was the case, I suspect it would have something to do with loading DOM resources as quickly as possible so they will be ready when they're needed. If the Image is not added to the document (meaning we remove `document.body.appendChild...`) it will not be requested.

You can keep  images from being loaded by using a `data-*` attribute instead. When the image is needed, swap the `src` value out for the `data-src` value, and at that point the browser will load the image:

```html
<img data-src="http://example.com/dont-load-me.png" />
```

The actual swap would be fairly straight-forward:

```js
imageReference.src = imageReference.getAttribute( "data-src" );
```

I should mention that I am an engineer on the Internet Explorer team.

Comment: I was originally looking more for someone who could give a breakdown of which browsers do what. However, this is incredibly helpful, and does actually answer the question. Thanks!

Comment: @saesris I tested a series of browsers and placed the results in the answer above. It seems as though all modern browsers today will load the image.

Answer (score 2):

With specific regard to images, this test has already been done by W3 located at: http://www.w3.org/2009/03/image-display-none/results

Comment: My concern with that test is that it was run in 2009. That's a very long time in browser development years.